# Was ist ein „Füllwort“?

Tags: word-usage

Nach Diskussionen in Kommentaren zur dieser Frage:

- [What's the difference between "jedenfalls" and "auf jeden Fall"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/whats-the-difference-between-jedenfalls-and-auf-jeden-fall)

habe ich mich auf die Suche nach einer guten Definition für *Füllwort* gemacht. Es gibt hierzu allerdings nur wenige und knappe Aussagen:

> - Wort mit geringem Aussagewert <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fuellwort)</sup>
> - im Kontext wenig auffallendes Wort mit geringem Aussagewert, Flickwort <sup>[DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=F%C3%BCllwort&view=1)</sup>
> - Linguistik, Literaturwissenschaft: ein Wort, das inhaltlich für überflüssig gehalten wird oder lediglich wegen des Sprachrhythmus eingefügt wird <sup>[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/F%C3%BCllwort)</sup>

Ist ein Füllwort ein Synonym zu [Expletivum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expletivum)? Gibt es für ein Wort sowohl eine Verwendung als Füllwort als auch nicht als Füllwort? Wie kann man ein Füllwort erkennen und ist die Verwendung von Füllwörtern schlechter Stil?

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wie andere das sehen, aber ich halte diesen Definition allesamt für Müll. Diese Wörter dienen der sozialen Regulation in verbaler Kommunikation, ihre Bedeutung liegt also weniger im Inhalt des Satzes, sondern mehr in seiner Bedeutung im Kontext. Ich kann nicht verstehen, warum diese Wörter immer als überflüssig angesehen werden, wenn sie doch eindeutig eine Funktion erfüllen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Füllwörter sind Wörter, die einen Satz auf*füllen*, aber zur eigentlichen Aussage des Satzes nichts (oder so gut wie nichts) beitragen. Man erkennt sie daran, dass man sie weglassen kann und keinem fällt’s auf (außer, dass der Satz dann kürzer ist).

> Ich werde wohl anscheinend morgen möglicherweise doch nicht kommen können.
>
> Ich werde wohl anscheinend morgen möglicherweise nicht kommen können.
>
> Ich werde wohl anscheinend morgen nicht kommen können.
>
> Ich werde wohl morgen nicht kommen können.
>
> Ich werde morgen nicht kommen können.

Erst der letzte Satz gibt der Aussage eine neue Note, da diese dort mit Bestimmtheit getroffen wird. Alle anderen Sätze drücken eine Unsicherheit aus, ob es klappt oder nicht.

Doch gibt es einen Unterschied in der Stärke dieser Unsicherheit, ob sie jetzt mit einem oder mit vier Wörtern ausgedrückt wird? [Eigentlich](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/was-meinen-wir-eigentlich-mit-eigentlich) nicht.

Alle Wörter, die weggelassen werden können, ohne wirklich was zu ändern, sind Füllwörter. Was nicht bedeutet, dass man alle Füllwörter eines Satzes bedenkenlos streichen darf. Denn wenn auch das *wohl* vom obigen Beispiel verschwindet, ändert sich die Bestimmtheit der Aussage. Doch kann man das *wohl* streichen und das *möglicherweise* stehen lassen, ohne den Effekt zu verändern.

*Expletivum* ist kein Synonym für *Füllwort*. Im Satz „Es regnet“ ist *es* das Expletivum und man kann es nicht weglassen, sonst hat man keinen Satz.

Ob die Verwendung schlechter Stil ist, lass ich die Leute beurteilen, die keinen haben. Allerdings wird ab einer gewissen Füllwortdichte das Lesen eines Satzes doch erschwert.

Comment: Für mich gibt es zwischen Satz 1 und Satz 2 sehr wohl einen Unterschied, nämlich den, dass in Satz 1 durch das doch impliziert wird, dass ursprünglich von meinem Kommen auszugehen war und sich nun die Situation geändert hat.

Comment: ***Es** regnet* ist kein Expletivum, denn wenn man einen Ort an erste Stelle zieht, bleibt das *es* erhalten, ist also valides Subjekt (*hier regnet **es***). Funktionieren würde allerdings ***es** wird gefeiert*: Setzt man hier ein *hier* ein entsteht ***hier** wird gefeiert*; das *es* verschwindet, es wird klar, dass es nur aus syntaktischen Gründen gebraucht wird.

Comment: Ich halte die ersten beiden Sätze für völlig überzogen. Hättest du das *`möglicherweise`* rausgeschmissen (und damit den zweiten Satz als Duplikat gestrichen), wäre es eine plausible Folge von Beispielen der Reduktion.

Answer (score 4):

> […] ist die Verwendung von Füllwörtern schlechter Stil?

Nehmen wir mal an, ich habe eine Sprechstunde bei meinem Professor zur Besprechung meiner Forschungsfortschritte. Ich beginne die Darlegung mit einem der folgenden Beispiele

> (A) In Hilberträumen gilt **ja** der Rieszsche Darstellungssatz
>
> (B) In Hilberträumen gilt der Rieszsche Darstellungssatz

Die Aussage (B) ist Gemeingut unter Mathematikern, jedoch möchte ich sie kurz ins Gedächtnis rufen. Ich müsste in Variante (B) jedoch mit meiner Intonation signalisieren, dass es bloß eine Erinnerung ist. Schlimm wäre es, würde ich den Eindruck erwecken, dass ich in dem Inhalt etwas Interessantes an sich finde, und noch schlimmer wäre es, würde ich den Eindruck erwecken, dass ich dem Professor dieses Wissen nicht zutraue.

Zum Glück existiert dieses Füllwort *ja*. Es signalisiert genau die Intention des Sprechaktes, indem es den Inhalt als trivial darstellt.

Umgekehrt verwenden Professoren auch mir gegenüber das *ja*, wenn sie mich nur erinnern wollen, oder mir zumindest die Chance geben, das Gesicht zu wahren und nicht als unwissend dazustehen.

In formaleren Schreiben würde man diese Funktion durch andere Füllwörter erfüllen lassen. Ein Mathematikbuch würde aussagen:

> (C) In Hilberträumen gilt bekanntermaßen der Rieszsche Darstellungssatz.

Faktisch gilt dies als Hinweis an den Leser, dem Wort *bekanntermaßen* gerecht zu werden, sollte er selber fachlich noch nicht so fortgeschritten sein. Auch hier wird eine soziale Funktion inkorporiert.

Addendum:
Die englische Wikipedia beschreibt einige Beispiele bereits ganz gut, und ich schließe mich dem Artikel voll und ganz an: [German modal particle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_modal_particle). Zitat:

> In the German language, a modal particle (German: Modalpartikel or Abtönungspartikel) is an uninflected word used mainly in spontaneous spoken language in colloquial registers. These words have a dual function: reflecting the mood or attitude of the speaker or narrator, and highlighting the sentence focus.
>
> The effect that a flavoring particle has is often vague and dependent on the overall context. Speakers often use them somewhat excessively, and sometimes combine several particles, as in doch mal, ja nun, or even ja doch nun mal. They are a feature typical of the spoken language.

Comment: Aber in Deinem Beispiel erfüllt das Wort *ja* bzw. *bekanntermaßen* eine Funktion, und ist daher eben kein Füllwort (zumindest nach den meisten Definitionen). Füllwörter lägen hier erst vor, wenn beide Konstruktionen gleichzeitig aufträten: *Wie jeder weiß, gilt in Hilberträumen ja bekanntermaßen der rieszsche Darstellungssatz.* (Es sei denn, man möchte aussagen, dass es allgemein bekannt ist, dass es allgemein bekannt ist, dass es allgemein bekannt ist, dass in Hilberträumen der rieszsche Darsetllungssatz gilt.)

Answer (score 3):

Nachdem John Smithers die meisten Fragen beantwortet hat, will ich mich auf diese kaprizieren:

> Gibt es für ein Wort sowohl eine Verwendung als Füllwort als auch nicht als Füllwort?

Es gibt viele Wörter, die je nach Kontext ein Füllwort sind oder nicht. Beispiele: Gerade, natürlich, eben.

*Natürlich* steht meist im Kontrast zu *künstlich*, zu *vom Menschen gemacht*, zu *kulturell*:

> Ein natürlicher Busen, eine natürliche Wasserzufuhr, eine natürliche Angst.

*Natürlich* wird aber auch zur Bekräftigung, wie *selbstverständlich* eingesetzt:

> Natürlich wird Bayern wieder Meister. Das interessiert die Bildungsbürger natürlich wenig.

Auch selbstverständlich wird oft zur Verstärkung eingesetzt, ohne dass es inhaltlich die Sache trifft. Interessanterweise ist die Bekräftigung das Gegenteil der John Smitherschen Relativierung. :)

Comment: Soll das heißen, dass das natürlich in dem Bayern-Beispiel ein Füllwort ist? Auf einer Ebene mit äh und tja und nun? Da muss ich protestieren. Alles was als Position 1 gilt kann meines Erachtens nach KEIN Füllwort sein, egal wie irrelevant die Information zu sein scheint. Und nebenbei gesagt... in diesem Beispiel kann natürlich sogar den Satzakzent tragen. Wo ist das ein Füllwort? Hat jemals tja einen Satzakzent getragen?

Comment: @Emanuel: Ist `äh` ein Füllwort? Und was bedeutet `als Position 1 gilt`? Dass der Satz mit `natürlich` beginnt, und umgestellt werden muss, wenn man darauf verzichtet?

Comment: Äh **ist** ein Füllwort (was nur in gesprochener Sprache auftritt). Und ein Wort, das an erster Stelle stehen kann und eine Funktion ausübt, ist **kein** Füllwort. Natürlich ist *natürlich* kein Füllwort.

Comment: Für Dich scheint Füllwort eine Eigenschaft zu sein, die an das Wort gebunden ist. Ich würde dagegen sagen, dass es eine Funktion ist, die ein Wort übernehmen kann, aber nicht muss. Ein Wort kann auch etwas bedeuten. Natürlich ist natürlich oft ein Füllwort aber natürlich nicht immer.

Answer (score 2):

Beim Füllwort ist der Name Programm. Es dient lediglich zum Füllen von z. B. Denkpausen, welche mit kurzen und für den Betroffenen eventuell unangenehmen Sprachpausen verbunden wären. Man erkennt diese daran, dass der Anwender diese zwar wiederholt ausspricht, in schriftlicher Form allerdings nicht zu Papier bringen würde. Der Grund dafür ist, dass man beim Schreiben in der Regel nicht akribisch beobachtet wird, man vor keiner Gruppe steht und ausreichend Zeit zum Formulieren hat.

Ein Beispiel folgt (von einem meiner Lehrer):

> In der zivilen Luftfahrt, ja, wird kein medizinischer Sauerstoff für die Druckkabine verwendet, ja. Man verwendet speziellen Flieger-Sauerstoff, ja. Der Unterschied, ja, liegt nicht in der Reinheit, ja. Ja. Die Reinheit, ja, liegt bei beiden Varianten, ja, bei 99,5 %, ja. Der Unterschied, ja, liegt hier, ja, im Anteil der Feuchtigkeit, ja. Ja. …

Eine andere Variante wäre, dass mir ein Lehrer eine Frage stellt, bei welcher ich im ersten Moment nicht weiß, wie ich die Antwort formulieren soll. Um mir eine Denkpause zu gönnen und dabei peinliche Stille zu vermeiden, könnte ich nun wie folgt beginnen:

> Jaaa …, ähhh …, also … im Grunde genommen …

Da ich persönlich Füllwörter für vollkommen nervig halte, lasse ich davon gänzlich ab. Ich brumme lieber ein viertelsekündiges *hmmm,* gefolgt von einer stillen Denkpause. Oder aber, wenn ich davon ausgehen muss, dass der Fragende nicht eben drei Sekunden abwarten kann, “bitte” ich um eine kurze Denkpause:

> Da müsste ich mal einen Moment nachdenken.

oder:

> Lassen Sie mich einen Moment nachdenken.

Comment: *`Beim Füllwort ist der Name Programm.`* -- gute Idee, finde ich. Auf ein Wort, dass die beschriebene Aufgabe erfüllt, passt dieser Name hervorragend. Nur ist die Sprache ja nicht so logisch, wie man am Dissens der hier versammelten Auffassungen sieht ;-)

Answer (score 0):

"Füllwörter" ist eine Verlegensheitsbezeichnung, weil man über diese Wortklasse noch nichts Rechtes zu sagen wußte. Sie tragen nichts zum Satzinhalt bei, aber zeigen uns Befindlichkeiten oder Stimmungsmodalitäten des Sprechers an, wie zB Freude, Ärger, Gereiztheit, Frust, kritische Haltung und anderes mehr. Lexika kommen mit diesen Füllwörtern oder Modalitätsanzeigern nicht zurecht, denn eine brauchbare Darstellung würde unverhätnismäßig viel Platz benötigen.

Von geringem Wert deutet auf völliges Unverständnis. Sie sind sozusagen das Salz und Gewürz in der Suppe.

Ein Beispiel: Das ist ja nicht war! / Das ist ja gelogen!
Was den Sinn betrifft, könnte man das "ja" weglassen. Aber es zeigt stärkste Entrüstung des Sprechers an.

Comment: *`es zeigt stärkste Entrüstung des Sprechers an`* -- hier würde ich widersprechen, es ist nicht so eindeutig. Mir scheint es vom Kontext abzuhängen und ist zudem regional unterschiedlich... Es ist doch spannend, wie schwer eine Definition von Füllwort fällt. ;-) und dabei findet man hier mehr als in der Wikipedia!